# How to let app.component know that user has logged in or logout Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

First time when web application loads, `app.component` is getting called and `navigationbar #1` showing up. Now when user login I want to load `navigationbar #2` from `app.component` (or let `app.component` UI know that user has logged in) so that `ng-template` can update UI and set `navigationbar #2`.
This is my code in `app.component.html` file

```
<div *ngIf="session === 'true'; else NoUserTemplete">
  <app-app-navigation-bar-admin></app-app-navigation-bar-admin>
</div>
<ng-template #NoUserTemplete>
  <app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
</ng-template>
```

`app.component.ts` file

```
constructor() {
  this.session = localStorage.getItem('isloggedin')
}
```

Below method called, when user hit Login button in `login.component`

```
UserLogin()
  {
    this.submitted = true;
    if(this.loginForm.invalid)
    {
      localStorage.removeItem("isloggedin");
      return
    }
    let data = { userName: this.loginForm.value.userName, txtemail:this.loginForm.value.txtEmail}
    localStorage.setItem("userinfo", JSON.stringify(data));
    localStorage.setItem('isloggedin','true');
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

Basically what I need is, whenever `localStorage`'s `isloggedin variable` is getting changed `app.component` should be aware about that and update the UI. How can I do that ?

Comment: The standard way is use guard on routes and in guard define your rule if token available then redirect to dashboard else login screen https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/auth-guards-in-angular-9-10-11/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a service to manage the `isLoggedIn` variable from the local storage. This service can also expose whatever is currently saved in the local storage at the moment. The benefit of this is that you can also expose some observable, to which you can subscribe from whichever component is interested in knowing when this variable changes (including `AppComponent`).

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class LoginService {
  private isLoggedInSource = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1);
  public isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.isLoggedInSource.asObservable();
    // sync initial value
    syncLoggedIn();
  }

  updateLoggedInStatus(isLoggedIn: boolean) {
    localStorage.setItem('isloggedin', isLoggedIn ? 'true' : 'false');
    syncLoggedIn();
  }
}

private syncLoggedIn(): void {
  this.isLoggedInSource.next(localStorage.getItem('isloggedin') === 'true');
}
```

Then in your login component you can inject the `LoginService` to be able to update the global `isLoggedIn` status.

```js
constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {}

UserLogin()
  {
    this.submitted = true;
    if(this.loginForm.invalid)
    {
      this.loginService.updateLoggedInStatus(false);
      return
    }
    let data = { userName: this.loginForm.value.userName, txtemail:this.loginForm.value.txtEmail}
    localStorage.setItem("userinfo", JSON.stringify(data));
    this.loginService.updateLoggedInStatus(true);
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

// in the logout method
// you also need to call this.loginService.updateLoggedInStatus(false);
```

Inside the `AppComponent` you can inject the same service to listen for the changes. Turn your `session` boolean property to an observable instead and use the `async` pipe:

```js
session$: Observable<boolean>;

constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
  this.session$ = loginService.isLoggedIn$;
}
```

And finally, in the template of your app component you can use the `session$` observable with the `async` pipe to decide which toolbar to show:

```html
<div *ngIf="session$ | async; else NoUserTemplete">
  <app-app-navigation-bar-admin></app-app-navigation-bar-admin>
</div>
<ng-template #NoUserTemplete>
  <app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Looks like you posted in JS or old typescript, but no issue I am able to modify.

Comment: @R15 Im curious, what is old typescript? Never heard about it. Also is there typescript syntax that could be confused with plain JS ?

Comment: @Tommi - instead of `setItem` I can see `localStorage.set` in code, not able to use `syncLoggedIn`, in `constructor` not accessible. that's why I said.

Comment: Its working. This was one of the best answer.

Comment: @R15 Sorry for the mistake, I did not write it in a code editor, I just wrote everything here in place. You can make the necessary adjustments in your code so that it doesn't have any errors

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use a service for this.

Notes:

- You can inject this service in any component (e.g. AppComponent) and then use the `async` pipe to check for the authentication status
- I suggest you to use only one variable in `localStorage` and then pipe this to the `isLoggedIn` status (also as an observable)

Here is an example implementation:

```
const USER_INFO_KEY = 'userinfo';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthService {
  private _userInfo$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserInfo | null>(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(USER_INFO_KEY))
  );
  public userInfo$ = this._userInfo$.asObservable();
  public isLoggedIn$ = this.userInfo$.pipe(
    map((userInfo) => Boolean(userInfo))
  );

  setUserInfo(userInfo: UserInfo | null) {
    localStorage.setItem(USER_INFO_KEY, JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    this._userInfo$.next(userInfo);
  }
}
```